# Can't understand OpenCV Python functions arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm learning OpenCV and also Python.
But I can't understand these funcions parameters:

```
cv2.Canny(image, threshold1, threshold2[, edges[, apertureSize[, L2gradient]]])
```

After ther argument "threshold2" I can't understand anymore, what does these [] means? It's a List? It's a silly question, but I really want to understand.

Comment: they're optional parameters. For learning purposes ignore them at first, then start playing with them until the edges look as you want them to

Comment: Thanks! So, if I want to put these optional parameters I will have to put all that are inside in the same [ ], right?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're familiar with C/C++, I found I could understand them better when I looked at them from point of view a language I already knew. They are parameters with default values. It means that if you do not supply any values for those parameters, they will use the default ones.

In C/C++ terms:

```
void point(int x = 3, int y = 4); // 3 , 4 are default values

point(1,2); // calls point(1,2)
point(1);   // calls point(1,4)
point();    // calls point(3,4)
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot! Get that, I think the c way to show this is more easy to understand.